# How to solve this "cursor" type query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in my table. BTW ... this is a DD/MM/YYYY format:

```
Date
18/09/2012
17/09/2012
13/09/2012
11/09/2012
10/09/2012
09/09/2012
25/08/2012
24/08/2012
```

The result what I want are:

```
Date
18/09/2012
13/09/2012
11/09/2012
09/09/2012
25/08/2012
```

The rule:
It starts from the latest date (18/09/2012) and check the next one down (17/09/2012). If there is a date then removed that from the list because it requires to have 1 day apart. Then goes to 13/09/2012 and then check 12/09/2012 and didn't find and then move to next one so on and so on. Basically you can't have date close each other (min 1 day apart).

Now I can do this on cursor if it's on TSQL however since I'm working on MySQL, is there any such thing in MySQL? Or perhaps any sub-queries approach that can solve this query?

I'm appreciated your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution -

```
SELECT date FROM (
  SELECT
    date, @d := IF(@d IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(@d, date) > 1, date, @d) start_date
  FROM
    dates,
   (SELECT @d:=null) t
  ORDER BY
    date DESC
) t
WHERE start_date = date
```

The subquery finds out start days (18, 13, 11...), then WHERE condition filters records. Try to run the subquery to understand how it works -

```
  SELECT
    date, @d := IF(@d IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(@d, date) > 1, date, @d) start_date
  FROM
    dates,
   (SELECT @d:=null) t
  ORDER BY
    date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    "MyTable1"."Date"
FROM
    "MyTable" AS "MyTable1"
    LEFT JOIN "MyTable" AS "MyTable2" ON
        ADDDATE("MyTable1"."Date", INTERVAL 1 DAY) = "MyTable2"."Date"
WHERE
    "MyTable2"."Date" IS NULL
ORDER BY
    "MyTable1"."Date" DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as I know about mysql query will be quit tricky and buggy if some how you manage to write the one. I suggest go for cursor, here is the syntax of the cursor, 
 [here is the syntax of the cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)